# jquery step through images

Tags: javascript, jquery

All I want to do is to be able to step through sequentially named images using up and down arrows.  I'm missing something simple and I can use some help.   The up and down fields do no work.  Any help is appreciated.  Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<div id = "up" class= "5" idnum= "number5">up up up</div>
<img src="img/n5.png" id = "number5">
<div id = "down" lass= "5" idnum= "number5">down down down</div>

<div id = "up" class= "26" idnum= "number4">up up up</div>
<img src="img/n26.png" id = "number4">
<div id = "down" lass= "26" idnum= "number4">down down down</div>

<div id = "up" class= "28" idnum= "number3">up up up</div>
<img src="img/n28.png" id = "number3">
<div id = "down" lass= "28" idnum= "number3">down down down</div>

<div id = "up" class= "30" idnum= "number2">up up up</div>
<img src="img/n30.png" id = "number2">
<div id = "down" lass= "30" idnum= "number2">down down down</div>

<div id = "up" class= "35" idnum= "number1">up up up</div>
<img src="img/n35.png" id = "number1">
<div id = "down" lass= "35" idnum= "number1">down down down</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#up").click(function () {
                var ball = $(this).attr("class");
                var idnum = $(this).attr("idnum");
                var test = $(this).find("img").attr("id");
                ball++;
                console.log("ball = "+ball);
                console.log("idnum = "+idnum);
                console.log("test = "+test);
                $("#"+idnum).attr("src","img/n"+ball+".png");

            });


            $("#down").click(function () {
                var ball = $(this).attr("class");
                var idnum = $(this).attr("idnum");
                var test = $(this).find("img").attr("id");
                ball--;
                console.log("ball = "+ball);
                console.log("idnum = "+idnum);
                console.log("test = "+test);
                $("#"+idnum).attr("src","img/n"+ball+".png");

            });
        });
    </script>
```

I know my code is really clunky and bloated at this point, but it's a result of multiple error tests and not getting stuff to work.

Comment: css classes aren't supposed to start with numbers.

Comment: You cant duplicate an ID.

Answer (score 0):

Gabe is correct; you can't use a certain ID more than once. My advice is to orient it this way:

```
<div id="pictureNavigator">
  <div class="upButton optionalOtherClass">up</div>
  <img src="n5.png"/>
  <div class="downButton">down</div>

<!-- ...etc...-->
</div>
```

But the rest of it I'm a bit confused about; can you just explain, visually, how you expect this thing to look, and we can give you basic ideas about the pattern to follow? (Keeping in mind, Stack Overflow tends not to do the whole work for you)

(After comment: ) So this sounds like something pretty simple to control on the Javascript side, rather than have HTML for each instance of it. The basic idea would be to maintain the image index (and upper/lower bounds) as Javascript variables, and replace the image's `src` attribute with the correct one on each click. I'll give a bit of unfinished code to show what I'm thinking.

```
$(function() {
    var imgIndex = 10;
    var minIndex = 0;
    var maxIndex = 55;

    function refreshIndex() {
        // here, set the image's src to "n13.png", or whatever imgIndex is.
    }

    $('#pictureNavigator .upButton').click(function() {
        imgIndex++;
        refreshIndex();
    });
    $('#pictureNavigator .downButton').click(function() {
        imgIndex--;
        refreshIndex();
    });
});
```

There might be a few other things to think about there, but I think that should be enough. As for the HTML, you should only need one up arrow, one down arrow, and one image. There may also be a way for you to pre-cache each image you're going to show the user, before it's displayed, if you like. (You may want to at least try figuring that one on your own though)

Comment: Sure thinng: basically, the user clicks an up arrow positioned over an image and the image is replaced with the next sequentially numbered one.  There's also a down arrow that does the same thing, but just goes down 1 instead of up.  

So, the user sees image 35 (n35.png) and clicks the up arrow: the image is replaced by image 36 (n36.png).

Comment: OK; added details to the answer